# Removing build folder from git

Tags: android, git

I have pushed a build folder to my remote repo; but the .gitignore file clearly has this line (/payu_ui/build); But i found out since the build files were already tracked once and now that i wrote a line in .gitignore will not really ignore the build folder. So i want to remove it from git from being tracked (the complete build folder) so i used this command

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch payu_ui/build/' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But every time i run this command it gives an err saying

```
fatal: bad revision 'rm'
```

So what is going wrong; every time i click the commit option from IDE it shows that 1300 files needs to be committed (its annoying me)

[image: When commit is cliked from IDE]

Any help will be appreciated;
 1. I dont want to track these build files(from payu_ui lib)
 2. I dont want to push them to remote repo (but its already thr and beleive once i track from local and push them it gets deleted in remote repo; if it doesn't i'll manually delete in remote repo)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well you may just do the following,

- Remove the line from gitignore for now.
- Locally delete the folder.
- Push out the change so the folder gets deleted from remote as well.
- Now add the line to gitignore.

I recently faced the problem and that is what i did.

Comment: can i delete my build folder locally, wont it effect?

Comment: yes delete the folder locally and commit the change. Then push it out. That would remove the folder from the remote. Then go ahead and add that line to gitignore so it does not happen in the future.

Comment: i'm on it; i'll update and how do i get to know whether the folder was deleted or not?; coz after running rm -r -f <folder to del> i can still see the folder in IDE; please guide me

Comment: Well i normally just delete it from the file system  :)

Comment: You could restart the IDE or refresh the project in the IDE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112157/discussion-between-djphy-and-som-bhattacharyya).

Answer (score 4):

remove those build files (or whole folder) from your computer

```
rm -r [direction to files]
```

then add, commit and push all your changes (actually the change will be removing those files from repository), if you have set `.gitignore`
 file properly, git will stop tracking those files